# Is there a way to parse in python a .txt file with having the user give a word to parse by?

Tags: parsing, user-input, python-3.7

I am hoping to be able to parse a .txt file but after taking user input for the keyword(s) that will be searched.

Comment: It seems like you don't need to *parse* the text file, you just need to search it for the user-supplied keyword(s).

Comment: ok, thank you very much